# Copying from text file inside foreach

Tags: powershell, loops

I am trying to copy a text file (one line at a time), open notepad++, run a macro on the one line and then append that text to another file. It runs the macro perfectly, however it is completely ignoring the text from $changefile and only copies $exportfile. Here is what I have so far

```
$exportfile=$args[0]
$changefile="Changefile.txt"
$inputfile="tick-import.txt"
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject wscript.shell;


$statement = get-content $exportfile
$newstatement = get-content $changefile
Start notepad++ $changefile
foreach($line in $statement) {  

    $line | out-file -Filepath $changefile 
    Sleep 2
    $wshell.SendKeys("^%1")
    Sleep 1

    foreach($line in $newstatement) {

        $line | out-file $inputfile -Append
    }
}
```

The second foreach is what isn't working.

Comment: that looks horribly fragile. [*grin*] what are you doing in notepad++ that you cannot do in PoSh?

Comment: I apologize for the very very late response. I am basically converting an plsql insert statement into an update, which I am doing in the npp macro. I've used powershell once before so I am unsure where I would start in order to do something like that.

Comment: thank you for the "why" of it. [*grin*] when you have an opportunity, you may want to dig thru the string operators in PoSh. plus, the `Select-String` cmdlet has some good ways to find things to apply various replacement steps to.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into that

Comment: you are quite welcome ... good luck! [*grin*]